# Weird Crash Report on Google Play Developer Console

Tags: android, exception

I have an app on the play store which has thrown an exception which I can see in the developer console. The error is as follows

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: MotionEvent { action=ACTION_UP, id[0]=0, x[0]=402.8711, y[0]=144.54651, toolType[0]=TOOL_TYPE_FINGER, buttonState=0, metaState=0, flags=0x0, edgeFlags=0x0, pointerCount=1, historySize=0, eventTime=1398177, downTime=1398087, deviceId=6, source=0x1002 } recycled twice!
at android.view.MotionEvent.recycle(MotionEvent.java:1659)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.finishMotionEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:2977)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverPointerEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:2968)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.handleMessage(ViewRootImpl.java:2522)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.processInputEvents(ViewRootImpl.java:862)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.handleMessage(ViewRootImpl.java:2531)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4944)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I do not understand what this exception is relating to. The app doesn't use any sensors, its a password manager so it doesn't use any sensors or fancy gestures so I don't understand what the MotionEvent ACTION_UP would be for.

Thanks for any help you can provide.

Comment: The trace starts with NativeStart (launching your app) and ends with an exception without, apparently, executing any of your code.  It smells like an Android bug to me.  Any common factors in devices and Android version in the logs?

Comment: Its only happened once but unfortunately the user didn't leave a message so the device isn't included

Comment: I've seen crashes only happen once, even on the same device with the same OS.  Maybe forget about it and worry if it happens again?

Comment: @Simon Yea I think that's what I am going to do. Hope it won't happen again no idea what to do if it does

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Motion Event action=ACTION_UP means that a gesture has ended at the described coordinates, means in this case that the finger goes up in the location x=402.8711, y=144.54651.
In other words: The error happend in this place.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MotionEvent.html#ACTION_UP

Comment: Thanks, that doesn't look as if its within my code, I don't use motion events within my app

Comment: yeah, you are right.
This are information for you, so you can know how it happend and in which case.